# Protobuf with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, protocol-buffers

I am using `protocol buffer` with the android `gradle` plugin to generate the java files.

This is the build.gradle file: I used the `protobuf-javalite` because my proto files contain Any

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    configurations {
//        implementation.exclude module:'proto-google-common-protos'
        implementation.exclude module: 'protolite-well-known-types'
        implementation.exclude module: 'protobuf-lite'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            proto {

            }
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/files/generated'
            }
        }
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.visualizer.proto"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.8.0'
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option "lite"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.8.0'
//    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.6.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
}
```

I have this code in the MainActivity:

```
EventOuterClass.Event.newBuilder().setType(EventOuterClass.Event.EventType.forNumber(0)) // product view
        .setCustomerId(123456789)
        .setSourceValue(EventOuterClass.Event.EventSource.ANDROID_VALUE)
        .setEntityId(10003457689)
        .build()
```

When I run the application, it is building but it is crashing

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.hicart.mobile.EventOuterClass$Event.dynamicMethod(EventOuterClass.java:1816)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.dynamicMethod(GeneratedMessageLite.java:336)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.isInitialized(GeneratedMessageLite.java:1514)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.isInitialized(GeneratedMessageLite.java:258)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$Builder.build(GeneratedMessageLite.java:433)
    at com.hicart.mobile.fragments.ProductFragment$onProductReady$1.run(MainActivity.kt:472)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Can you put the full stacktrace here?

Comment: The error has changed. Now it won't build. I updated the question with the build error.

Comment: I believe you need to invalidate caches and restart. To check that you are able to import this class, just type EnumVerifier and see if AndroidStudio can locate it in auto complete or not. I imported the `implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.8.0'` dependency and I was able to import the EnumVerifier fine.

Comment: still the same error ..

Comment: To check that you are able to import this class, just type EnumVerifier and see if AndroidStudio can locate it in auto complete or not. I imported the implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.8.0' dependency and I was able to import the EnumVerifier fine.

Comment: Try that and let me know if you are able to import this class.

Comment: I can import the class but once I do, it gives me an error on EnumVerifier after the autocomplete of Internal.EnumVerifier

Comment: @RajanPrasad now the application is built again, can you please check the crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering how it was solved, I added the Any file from Google's protobuf manually in the project.

I guess this is a temporary solution until a new update comes out.